# Se puede cambiar if por el ciclo For? (PYTHON)

Tags: python

Tengo este programa, funciona correctamente con el if, pero no sé si existe la manera de ejecutarlo usando for,aún soy muy principiante y la verdad no sabría como hacerlo. ¿Alguien podría decirme si es posible?

```
nombre = (input ('Ingresa tu nombre: '))
print("Productos")
print("1. Pantalon $500")
print("2. Short $300")
print("3. Playera $350")
opcion = input("Selecciona opcion: ")

if opcion == "1":
   descuento = 500 * 0.20
   precio_final = 500 - descuento
   print(f"Nombre del cliente: {nombre}")
   print(f"Precio con descuento: {precio_final}")
   opcion2 = input("¿Quieres hacer otro calculo?: ")

elif opcion == "2":
    descuento = 300 * 0.10
    precio_final = 300 - descuento
    print(f"Nombre del cliente: {nombre}")
    print(f"Precio con descuento {precio_final}")
    opcion2 = input("¿Quieres hacer otro calculo?: ")

elif opcion == "3":
    descuento = 350 * 0.12
    precio_final = 350 - descuento
    print(f"Nombre del cliente: {nombre}")
    print(f"Precio con descuento {precio_final}")
    opcion2 = input("¿Quieres hacer otro calculo?: ")
```

Comment: Si, tampoco le encuentro el sentido yo, pero esto fue un trabajo que me dejaron, solo que me prohibieron usar el if, pero desde luego se ve que es imposible hacerlo sin el if, y pues con el for no tiene sentido porque este es para ciclos, como ya comentaste.

Comment: Pues si no te dejan usar el `if` veo que en python no existe el switch, que podría reemplazarlo perfectamente en otros lenguajes, pero veo una cosa llamada `diccionarios` en [esta web](https://www.codigopiton.com/como-hacer-switch-case-en-python/) donde explican alternativas al if.

Comment: Python ya implementa `switch-case` lo que se conoce como `match-case`, pero solo está disponible en versiones 3.10 en adelante!

Comment: Pues segun veo en la respuesta de @CandidMoe sí que hay una forma de hacerlo con el **for** (je, he borrado mi anterior comentario por ello). En fín, espero que te funcione. Saludos!

Answer (score 2):

Si realmente quieres hacer un "if" con un "for", puedes usar el siguiente hack:

```
if a == "1":
```

lo puedes reemplazar con

```
for x in {"1"}.intersection({a}):
```

Funciona así:

- `{"1"}` es un conjunto (*set*) compuesto de un único elemento, que es el valor constante contra el que queremos comparar.
- `{a}` es el elemento incógnito, que también hemos transformado en un conjunto.

Tenemos dos conjuntos de un elemento cada uno: La intersección de ellos será vacía si los elementos no coinciden, por lo que el `for` fallara al no tener nada sobre lo que iterar.

#### Demo

```
nombre = (input ('Ingresa tu nombre: '))

while True:
    print("Productos")
    print("1. Pantalon $500")
    print("2. Short $300")
    print("3. Playera $350")
    opcion = input("Selecciona opcion: ")

    for i in {"1"}.intersection({opcion}):
       print(1)
       descuento = 500 * 0.20
       precio_final = 500 - descuento
       print(f"Nombre del cliente: {nombre}")
       print(f"Precio con descuento: {precio_final}")

    for i in {"2"}.intersection({opcion}):
        print(2)
        descuento = 300 * 0.10
        precio_final = 300 - descuento
        print(f"Nombre del cliente: {nombre}")
        print(f"Precio con descuento {precio_final}")

    for i in {"3"}.intersection({opcion}):
        print(3)
        descuento = 350 * 0.12
        precio_final = 350 - descuento
        print(f"Nombre del cliente: {nombre}")
        print(f"Precio con descuento {precio_final}")
```

produce:

```
Ingresa tu nombre: Candid Moe
Productos
1. Pantalon $500
2. Short $300
3. Playera $350
Selecciona opcion: 1
1
Nombre del cliente: Candid Moe
Precio con descuento: 400.0
Productos
1. Pantalon $500
2. Short $300
3. Playera $350
Selecciona opcion: 2
2
Nombre del cliente: Candid Moe
Precio con descuento 270.0
Productos
1. Pantalon $500
2. Short $300
3. Playera $350
Selecciona opcion: 3
3
Nombre del cliente: Candid Moe
Precio con descuento 308.0
Productos
1. Pantalon $500
2. Short $300
3. Playera $350
Selecciona opcion:
```

Answer (score 0):

Si lo que intentas es hacer es algo parecido a un menú, más que un **for**, necesitarías un **while**, por ejemplo:

```
nombre = (input ('Ingresa tu nombre: '))

while True:
    print("Productos")
    print("1. Pantalon $500")
    print("2. Short $300")
    print("3. Playera $350")
    opcion = input("Selecciona opcion: ")

   if opcion == "1":
       descuento = 500 * 0.20
       precio_final = 500 - descuento

   elif opcion == "2":
       descuento = 300 * 0.10
       precio_final = 300 - descuento

   elif opcion == "3":
       descuento = 350 * 0.12
       precio_final = 350 - descuento

   else:
       break

   print(f"Nombre del cliente: {nombre}")
   print(f"Precio con descuento {precio_final}")
   opcion = input("¿Quieres hacer otro calculo?: ")
```